# How to link a UICollectionViewCell to a UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UICollectionView` on it but Xcode doesn't seem to look like every tutorial I find on the Internet or on YouTube - When I drag a `UICollectionViewCell` to place in the `UICollectionView`, it won't let me place it.

Now I'm confused as to how I can link my cell to the `UICollectionView`.
This is the viewController.h file:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [self.imagesArray count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

ImageViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];



NSString *myImageString = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:myImageString];


return cell;
}

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return CGSizeMake(100.0, 100.0);
}

-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.collectionView.delegate = self;
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;


//[self.collectionView registerClass:[ImageViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imageCell"];

self.imagesArray = @[@"shirt1.PNG", @"pants.png", @"pants2.png"];
}
```

I'm not using a Storyboard interface but individual xib's. When I run this all that appears is the blank black screen. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

[-registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/registerNib%3aforCellWithReuseIdentifier%3a)

If you have your cell defined in a NIB, then you register that NIB with the collection view. That is how the collection view know what to load when `-dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` is called.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // …

    UINib nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"<the name of your xib>" bundle:nil];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imageCell"];

    // …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't have new a object of `UICollectionViewCell` in this method:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The "cell" in your method must be set to `nil`.